How can I make a colorpicker start on picking functionality?
I have a color picker coded with Vue 3 and tailwind
<input id="colorPickerBtn" type="color" class="opacity-0 absolute">

and when I open it, it opens the default browser color picking popup

I want it to initialize in color picking functionality (the one highlighted on the screenshot), there's a way to do it (feel free to explain that in regular JS)?

Wouldn't you just set the value to the default option? <input id="colorPickerBtn" type="color" class="opacity-0 absolute" value="#EF4444">?

@mykaf i don't want a default value. I want it to start on color picking itself as i did clicked on this funcionality instead of opening the color range and stuff

What do you mean by "color picking itself"?

@mykaf https://prnt.sc/1eZTq7WleRSW that's color picking... otherwise it offers you a color "choosing", you see a grid with a lot of colors and you CHOOSE one of them, color picking is: you click on a color and it turns the event.target.value

I'm not following. Are you trying to use it to set an element's color? If so, you could probably add an "change" listener to the color input. Or are you differentiating between "picking" and "choosing" (they are are the same, as far as I'm concerned).

I have an button, that button is my color picker. When clicking on that button instead of opening a rainbow full of colors for me to choose i want it to execute exactly this funcionality i highlighted on the first screenshot

Your screenshot isn't specific about the functionality and there's nothing highlighted..

@mykaf then you're not openning them lol, both of them have a RED (Red highlight on white background, can't be more clear than it) arrow/block...

One of them has an arrow, but it's unclear what the item it's pointing to is supposed to do or mean. Are you trying to pick a color from the screen? Rather than a color-chooser/picker, it seems like you'd need to toggle it "on", then add an event listener to the window to get the element's color.

I think you're referring to the eyedropper functionality that is built-in to some browsers. Chrome has some documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/eyedropper
As a warning, it's only supported in the Chrome and Edge browsers. If you wanted to go that route, you might be able to implement it like
<button id="colorPickerButton">

...

let chosenColor 

document.getElementById('colorPickerButton').addEventListener('click', (event)=>
    chosenColor = await startEyeDropper()
})
async function startEyeDropper() {
    if (('EyeDropper' in window)) {
        const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();
        try {
          const result = await eyeDropper.open();
          return result.sRGBHex;
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
    } else {
        alert('eyedropper not supported')
    }  
  }

My other thought is since you're already using Vue, you might try using a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-eye-dropper to implement an eyedropper, which will probably have better cross-browser support anyway.
